# Process.Start("IExplore.exe"); --> System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Been trying to run this simple code is it's driving me nuts as it doesn't work.

I was also expecting Visual Studio to break the program in the line where I get the error but it breaks on the function call and not inside of the function as you can see in the picture bellow.

```
        OpenFolder();

        private void OpenFolder()
        {
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"c:\temp");

        }
```

And I get:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

[image]

Comment: That message is typically a sign of a .NET 6+/Core process attempting to load a .NET Framework assembly (or vice versa, depending on the version numbers involved), which in turn attempts to load a system assembly that doesn't exist (at least not in that form) in the runtime. Check for such a platform mismatch.

Comment: @jdweng: no. `Process.Start` calls out to `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecute` (depending on how it's invoked), both of which search many more paths than just the current one. In any case, that has nothing to do with the error here as it isn't `Process.Start` which is throwing the exception.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Process has no environment variables so there is NO path.

Comment: @jdweng: What process are you talking about? Every process has environment variables. Only if you take special care to give a process an empty environment block are there no environment variables, and I see nothing in the OP's question that would imply that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Then you never used Process. I've used process a lot and there is not PAT variable defined.  When you run an app in windows you automatically get the PATH of the parent process.  Process class in c# does not do that automatically.

Comment: @jdweng your argument is irrelevant. JeroenMosters is right - .net core app is trying to load .net framework assmebly. processes and paths are red herring in this case.

Comment: @jdweng: Perhaps you're thinking of the fact that `Process.Start` with no further arguments may end up using `ShellExecute` to start the process -- I would image that indeed will not lead to a child process in the normal sense of the word, so the resulting process will not inherit the parent's environment. However, this has nothing at all to do with `Process.Start` using the `PATH` of the *calling process*, which is all that matters for resolving the path of the executable. ...in any case all of this is irrelevant because, again, `Process.Start` is *never even getting called* in this scenario.

Comment: @JeroenMostert could you elaborate more how I can `Check for such a platform mismatch.` I really don't know do to that.

Comment: Your solution likely has more than one project with the projects targeting different frameworks, or else your project is referring to an external assembly or package that was built for .NET Framework when your project is running on .NET Core (or vice versa), or else something has gone really wrong with the build. If you are on .NET Core or have a library targeting .NET Standard, try including the `System.Diagnostics.Process` NuGet package. I should think this is unnecessary for .NET 6, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of the problem: Because UseShellExecute defaults to false on .NET 6. When UseShellExecute = false, the code will use the incoming parameter as the filename, throwing a "The system cannot find the file specified" exception.

Reason:

UseShellExecute defaults to false on .NET 6:

```
public bool UseShellExecute { get; set; }
```

Defaults to true on the .NET Framework:

```
 [DefaultValue(true)]
 [MonitoringDescription("ProcessUseShellExecute")]
 [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
 public bool UseShellExecute
{
     get
    {
         return this.useShellExecute;
     }
     set
    {
        this.useShellExecute = value;
     }
 }

     private bool useShellExecute = true;
```

Solution:

1. Set UseShellExecute = true.
2. Use .NET Framework to develop projects.

Code testing in .Net6:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        // Define an instance of processstartinfo
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("explore.exe");
        startinfo.FileName = @"C:\test\test.txt";
        startinfo.UseShellExecute = true;
       

        // start the process
      
        try
        {
            Process.Start(startinfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Test Results:

[image]

UseShellExecute defaults to false:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        // Define an instance of processstartinfo
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("explore.exe");
        startinfo.FileName = @"C:\test\test.txt";
       
       

        // start the process
      
        try
        {
            Process.Start(startinfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Test Results:

[image]

Comment: Read the error message again; the name of the file not found is `System.Diagnostics.Process`, not whatever is passed to `Process.Start`. When that is fixed this issue could come into play, but it's not yet.

Comment: I think you were trying to tell me that from the beginning and I wasn't yet up to speed on what you mean. In the end, with the info you gave me, I figured out that I was trying to run .NET code on project created for UWP, so the namespaces I was using were also not working because of the different Frameworks.

I got it work, once I changed that to the correct project seetings.